# test suite python - webdriver

Tags: python, testing, webdriver, suite

I'm new with python, and I'm trying to create my own test suite.

The main pourpose is to execute the same test on different browser, that's why I used the variable browser, that is used within the test to call the webdriver.

I have this:

> def test_01(self,browser):
>
> def test_02(self,browser):

my Suite:

```
    def suite():
        test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(Test01))
        return test_suite
```

main:

```
     if __name__ == "__main__":
             suite1 = unittest.TestSuite()
             self = Test01()
             suite1.addTest(Test01.test_01(self, 'firefox'))
             suite1.addTest(Test01.test_02(self, 'firefox'))
             unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())
```

When I try to execute that script, the first one test is execute, the second one not, and I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "SuiteWebMail.py", line 138, in 
>      suite1.addTest(Test01.test_01(self, 'firefox'))
>    File "c:\Python34\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 50, in addTest
>      raise TypeError("{} is not callable".format(repr(test)))
>   TypeError: None is not callable

Thank you in advance

C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe isn't a Pythonic way, but I found a solution:

```
class Test01(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_login(self):
        self.page = "https://myWebPageAddress"
        self.username = "userName"
        self.password = "Password"
        self.browser_label = ['firefox', 'chrome', 'ie']

        for index in range(len(self.browser_label)):
            self.browser_name = self.browser_label[index]


            if self.browser_name == 'firefox':
                logger.debug("Opening [" + self.browser_name + "] ...")
                self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            if self.browser_name == 'chrome':
                logger.debug("Opening [" + self.browser_name + "] ...")
                self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            if self.browser_name == 'ie':
                logger.debug("Opening [" + self.browser_name + "] ...")
                self.driver = webdriver.Ie()

            try:
                logger.info("Test_01::Case_01::Login OK")
                Test01.case_01(self)
            except BaseException as e:
                logger.fatal(e.value)
        logger.info("End")
        self.driver.close()

    def case_01(self):
    ....
    ....
```

I hope that's could be helpfull for someone.