# can't run CHROME using selenium webdriver remote

Tags: java, python, google-chrome, selenium

I am using python with selenium webdriver to run and automate test cases on a grid. I am able start the FIREFOX browser with some warning messages on both hub and node, but it works fine. But the issue is starting the same web application using CHROME. I tried everything possible, but no help.
Whenever I have to start off with the CHROME browser locally, I used to run the `chromedriver.exe` to start the app. but I don't know how to parse the `chromedriver.exe` remotely to start the same app there. I have even tried installing and started running the chromedriver on the node and checked f it starts running but it was of no help.And have set the system property as well...

```
java -jar ./selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar - Dwebdriver.chrome.driver='/opt/drivers/chromedriver' -role webdriver -hub  http://192.168.1.10:4444/grid/register -port 5566 -browser browserName=chrome
```

output:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_search_in_python_org (__main__.PythonOrgSearch)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\bharath.py", line 13, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://192.168.1.62:4444/wd/hub',DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.47.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.47.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 136, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.47.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 196, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.47.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\user\'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver.exe'
Stacktrace:
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState (Preconditions.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable (DriverService.java:121)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable (DriverService.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$0 (ChromeDriverService.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable (ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build (DriverService.java:290)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService (ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init> (ChromeDriver.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor (DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance (DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance (DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call (DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call (DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run (DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1.310s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Please help me out here...

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems that you're try to open the file pointing in the wrong location:

> ```
> WebDriverException: Message: The driver executable does not exist:
>   C:\Users\user\'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver.exe' Stacktrace:
> ```

btw isn't clear why you're trying to start chromedriver with java if you're using python..

If you're using python you can check this: 
[test suite python - webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535854/test-suite-python-webdriver)

Best Regards
Claudio

Comment: coz I am running an selenium grid.

Comment: The chromedriver is installed on both hub and node on the grid. Since I have to start the driver; I am not sure whether I have to run it on Node or on Hub. I tried both the ways, it just did not work !